# Why are my objects not keeping the data they are constructed with?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, adt, logcat

I am building an Android application in Java to navigate three buildings on a campus. The user enters the room number of the room they are in, and the room number of the room they wish to travel to, and are given directions to get from one to the other.

As part of this, I made a WorldMap class to hold the map, and defined in it a bunch of nodes to use for pathfinding. The nodes declare perfectly fine as far as I've been able to tell, yet when I tried to access them from within the WorldMap class's methods, the program threw a NullPointerException. I investigated this, and Eclipse tells me that every single one of the nodes' fields are set to null values.

While I'm not entirely new to Java, I am still relatively new, having used pretty much entirely C++ in the past, and I have absolutely no idea what I am looking at here and no idea where to start looking.

On to the code, then.

This is an example of how the nodes are declared:

```
Node g2 = new Node(
    new ConnectionTo[] {
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.north),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,3,8)), new Room[]{}, Direction.east),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,4,7)), new Room[]{}, Direction.south),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,3,6)), new Room[]{new Room("104",new String[]{"left","right"}),new Room("120",new String[]{"right","left"})}, Direction.west),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.up),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.down)
    },  new Coordinates(0,3,7)
);
```

This is how the nodes are stored:

```
Node[][][] map =
{
    {   //first floor
        //00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, cls, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //00
        {dne, dne, dne, dne,  oc,  cl,  cf, dne, dne, dne}, //01
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //02
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, og2,  g4,  gc,  g2, gs1, dne}, //03
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, gs2,  g1,  g3, dne}, //04
        {dne, ot3, dne, ot1,  op, dne, og1, gal, dne, dne}, //05
        {dne, ot4, dne, dne, dne, dne,  a2,  a1, dne, dne}, //06
        {dne,  t3, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  a3,  as, dne}, //07
        {dne,  t1, tl1, ot2, dne, dne, dne,  a4, dne, dne}, //08
        { ts,  t2, tl2, ot5, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //09
        {dne,  t4, tls, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //10
    },
    {   //second floor
        //00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, CLS, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //00
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  CL,  C2,  C4, dne, dne}, //01
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  C1,  C3,  C5, dne, dne}, //02
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  G4, GC1,  G3, GS1, dne}, //03
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, GC2, dne,  G1,  G2, dne}, //04
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, GS2, dne, GAL, dne, dne}, //05
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A5,GALS, dne, dne}, //06
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A3,  A1, dne, dne}, //07
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A2,  AS, dne}, //08
        { TS,  T4,  T3, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //09
        {dne, TLS,  TL, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //10
    }
};
```

This is the "dne" node: `static Node dne = new Node();`

Relevant parts of Node.java:

```
public class Node
{
    ConnectionTo n, e, s, w, u, d;
    ConnectionTo[] dirArr;
    boolean[] hasConnection;
    Coordinates coords;
    boolean exists;
    Coordinates targetCoordsHolder;

    Node () { exists = false; }
    Node (ConnectionTo[] connections, Coordinates location)
    {
        hasConnection = new boolean[6];
        exists = true;
        n = connections[0];
        e = connections[1];
        s = connections[2];
        w = connections[3];
        u = connections[4];
        d = connections[5];
        dirArr = connections;
        coords = location;
        for (int i = 0; i < dirArr.length; i++)
        {
            hasConnection[i] = false;
            if (dirArr[i].exists) { hasConnection[i] = true; }
        }
        if (location.equals(new Coordinates()))
        {
            exists = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant parts of ConnectionTo.java:

```
public class ConnectionTo
{
    Direction dir;
    Room[] rooms;
    Node targetNode;
    boolean exists = true;
    double cost;
    public ConnectionTo (Node target, Room[] rms, Direction pdir, double cost)
    {
        if (target.coords.equals(new Coordinates())) { exists = false; }
        if (!target.exists)
        {
            exists = false;
            return;
        }
        targetNode = target;
        rooms = rms;
        dir = pdir;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    public ConnectionTo() { exists = false; }
    public ConnectionTo (Direction pdir)
    {
        this(new Node(), new Room[]{}, pdir, 256);
    }
    public ConnectionTo (Node target, Room[] rms, Direction pdir)
    {
        this (target, rms, pdir, 256);
    }
}
```

The relevant parts of Room.java:

```
public class Room
{
    String name;
    int num;
    boolean nonstandardMsg;
    String[] msgs;

    Room (String roomName, int roomNum, String[] approachMsgs)
    {
        this(roomName, roomNum, approachMsgs, false);
    }
    Room (String roomName, int roomNum, String[] approachMsgs, boolean nsp)
    {
        name = roomName;
        num = roomNum;
        msgs = approachMsgs;
        nonstandardMsg = nsp;
    }
    Room (String roomName, String[] approachMsgs)
    {
        this(roomName, approachMsgs, false);
    }
    Room (String roomName, String[] approachMsgs, boolean nsp)
    {
        name = roomName;
        //if first character is a number
        if (roomName.charAt(0) == '1' || roomName.charAt(0) == '2' || roomName.charAt(0) == '3' || roomName.charAt(0) == '4' || roomName.charAt(0) == '5' || roomName.charAt(0) == '6' || roomName.charAt(0) == '7' || roomName.charAt(0) == '8' || roomName.charAt(0) == '9' || roomName.charAt(0) == '0')
        {
            //if last character is number
            if (roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '1' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '2' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '3' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '4' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '5' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '6' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '7' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '8' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '9' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '0')
            {
                num = Integer.parseInt(roomName);
            }
            else
            {
                num = Integer.parseInt(roomName.substring(0, roomName.length() - 2));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            num = Integer.parseInt(roomName.substring(1));
        }
        msgs = approachMsgs;
        nonstandardMsg = nsp;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention - I am building this for Android 4.3 using ADT, including the built-in emulator and debugger.

EDIT 2: As the WorldMap.java file is nearly 900 lines long, I've put it up on Pastebin at this link: http://pastebin.com/zcaxuSCt

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger.  Most likely you have a bug in your code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Doing exactly that is what led me to discover that the fields are somehow becoming null after I am done constructing them. I wrote as much at the top of the question.

Comment: You appear to be creating new objects in your code which won't do anything useful. I suspect you are initialising one object and then throwing it away and using another.  Can you show which line this "turning into null" happens?

Comment: @Invictus Setting a watch on one of these nodes will allow you to see exactly where it is becoming null if you run line by line through the execution.

Comment: BTW Character.isDigit(ch)  will tell you if a character is a digit.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There is a significant amount of code I did not include for brevity's sake, such as the pathfinding code and the tab layouts, which I'd thought wouldn't add anything to the question. That's where those unused fields are going. The fields become null the moment the largest node constructor (in the example I gave in the question, that would be the "g2" object) finishes.

Comment: @LexWebb I have done so, using the ADT built-in debugger. Which I just realized I forgot to mention in the question. Whoops.

Comment: The main difference between java and C++ is that java always pass objects by reference, re-read your code and find where you are expecting an object to be copied... Also this line "if (target.coords.equals(new Coordinates()));" does nothing.

Comment: You have this in the above code:
static Node dne = new Node();

However, there's no code shown that initializes the new Node and I don't see an empty constructor for the Node class. If this is the only line related to setting up dne, then this is the problem (the above will simply create a new, empty Node object with none of the internal fields initialized)

Comment: @Invictus So you are saying that `g2` becomes `null`? And there is no other g2 in your code which you could be using by mistake?

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux, Java only uses pass by value http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: @Greg Ah, I missed that - it is `Node () { exists = false; }`. I'll add that to the question in a moment

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux That line checks to see if the coordinates of the target node are the default values for a Coordinates object - namely, `x=-1; y=-1; z=-1;`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No - `g2` does not become `null`, its internal fields, such as `n`, `e`, `coords`, and so on are what become `null`

Comment: @dcharms. That's playing with words, your article says 'Object references are passed by value'. So java behave exactly as C++ when you pass objects by reference, and it's easier for a C++ developer to say it this way.

Comment: @Invictus yes, but what does it do when this is the case ? There is a semicolomn closing the if statement. if (condition); is no op until condition has a side effect (then the if is useless).

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux that's not exactly true. If you look at the "litmus test", in C++ I would be able to set the reference passed by reference to a new Object or null. You cannot do that in Java.

Comment: Can you post the LogCat output so we can see the stack trace?

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux I am aware of this behavior, and I don't see anywhere in my code where I am expecting something to be copied/not copied when it is actually not copied/copied.

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux I found the line you were referring to and fixed it. Feel a bit silly for missing that, though it shouldn't do much as `target.exists` should always be false if that if statement evaluates to true. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Greg The LogCat output wouldn't be relevant, I would think - the NullPointerException was only the impetus to investigate further and discover the problem in the question. Also, I don't have enough rep to post images, so I really don't want to type out all of the console output (can't copy-and-paste from the terminal) if I don't need to. So, ah... how important is it?

Comment: I'm not clear on what line of code is throwing the NPE specifically... Did I miss that in the text above?

Comment: Seeing the WorldMap class may help the most since that's where the problem apparently is...

Comment: @Greg The class is 886 lines of code in all, so I'm a bit wary of pasting it into the question, but I'll throw it up on Pastebin ( http://pastebin.com/zcaxuSCt ). The exception gets thrown at line 662.

Comment: @Invictus, I admit being stumped thus far. Here's a suggestion though. Set a breakpoint on line 688 (repeated below) and check each parameter before the recursion is invoked. 

pathList.add(makePath(startNode, endNode, pathSoFar, closedNodes, openNodes));

One other thing that may be a problem: in coordAtDir(), you are essentially setting indexes into the map array if I understand the overall logic correctly. There is no bounds check going on here to validate that x, y, and z still point to valid values. Subsequently trying to access map[c.z][c.y][c.x] would spark an NPE